# How can I get Jupyter '%%cython' style performance highlighting in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, cython, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter Notebook has a neat feature where it'll highlight lines of Cython code that are causing slowdown due to coupling with Python. It'd be really neat to get that kind of functionality in Pycharm when writing Cython code as well.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Even without Jupyter, I believe the `cython` can produce an `html` with this kind of highlighting.

Comment: @hpaulj Do you happen to know how to make it do that?

Comment: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html - it's the `-a` option.  Similar to the `--annotate` command in the `notebook`.  http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html#using-the-ipython-notebook looks like the `notebook` just includes this `html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the best way is to do this:

1. Open a command prompt in the same directory as your `.pyx` source code
2. Run `cython --annotate yourcode.pyx`
3. Open yourcode.html to see the results.

There doesn't appear to be a Pycharm extension that integrates the highlighting in to the Pycharm code view itself.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj mentions, you can use the `-a` option with the cython magic

eg.

```
%%cython -a

# your cython code here
```